# iOS Storyboard Event being raised twice (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a basic iOS app as a way to learn SWIFT (I come from a .NET background), and have encountered an issue where my button's click method is being called twice for a single touch.

The button's definition in the storyboard is:

```
<button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gd0-8i-21X">
                                <rect key="frame" x="168" y="408" width="264" height="30"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Login">
                                    <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                </state>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="TryLogin:" destination="2H8-Z2-w9l" eventType="touchUpInside" id="Gdv-wK-xhp"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
```

And the method that is attached to the event is:

```
  @IBAction func TryLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (!_LoggingIn) {
            _LoggingIn = true
            // Login user through a web-service.           
            _LoggingIn = false
        }
    }
```

I have additional code that logs the user in, and conditionally performs a segue, but I have removed it for simplicity (the method is called twice regardless).

I have tried deleting the View Controller and rebuilding it from scratch, programmatically attaching the event handler to the button object by creating an IBOutlet for the button and the following code:

.addTarget(self, action: "TryLogin:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

The method is appropriately called in either case - but it is always being called twice per 'click'. When I debug through it, the second event is typically raised about halfway through the first execution. This is on a iPad Mini 2, running iOS 8.1.3. I was very careful to remove the designer code attaching the button when I used the IBOutlet, and conversely to remove the IBOutlet when I was using the designer.

Here's an example of the IBOutlet method I used:

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var _UserName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var _Password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var _Login: UIButton!
    private var _LoggingIn: Bool = false   


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        _Password.secureTextEntry = true;   
        _Login.addTarget(self, action: "TryLogin:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func TryLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (!_LoggingIn) {
            _LoggingIn = true  
            // Do login work.                
            _LoggingIn = false
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated, as I've been going in circles on this for a while now.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you add another button to the same view but for some another IBAction callback?

Comment: I just tried that and it worked - I'm at a loss as to why but thank you! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add another button to the same view but for some another IBAction callback